# Connect server database from client PC using Power Query in Microsoft Excel

Tags: mysql, database, excel, server, powerquery

I'm always getting this error when trying to connect database from server via client pc.

I'm using power query in excel to connect but the error "*the user was not authorised*" appeared. These are the steps I'm doing in Microsoft Excel:

1. Select tab Power Query.
2. Choose From MySQL Database.
3. Fill in server IP address and database name.
4. Choose Windows -> Use alternate credentials -> fill in username and password of pc that act as server.

Is it true that I have to use username & password from windows pc server? So, why I'm getting this error or do you have any other way to connect server database using Microsoft Excel? I can't figured it out because I'm always getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: Do you have separate username/password credentials for the database? You might want to try using Database authentication, which you can access by clicking on the label below Windows in that dialog.

Comment: I have set username/password in database by click the privileges in phpmyadmin. But, I'm still get the same error when use Database authentication. I have not idea why.